# How would I do this mod_rewrite to work as I need?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Realize there are other questions posted about this, but I wasn't able to find one that worked specifically for what I need to do. Apologies if I overlooked a potential solution.

This is how I would want URLs to be used/requested:

`http://mysite.com/read/comics/all-star-superman/all-star-superman-01/1`

This is how I currently have it working:

`http://mysite.com/read/index.php?dir=Comics/All%20Star%20Superman&file=All%20Star%20Superman%2001.cbr&page=1`

The `dir` variable can be however long. It's not always going to be 2 deep. This is really the part that's wracking my brain. Also, I want to drop the extension off the file, so I'd need to be able to differentiate that from a normal directory.

My only guess is to send the entire URI request over to index.php, then parse it from there. I would need to verify the last value after the last `/` is numerical (easy enough), and then if that's the case, the value below it would be the filename. I guess I could then verify it by doing a `file_exists()` with an added extension of .cbz/.cbz and seeing which works. But I guess where I'm falling short is what if a request for a directory/file goes through, but no page (so there's not a trailing numerical page value). How would I tell if it's a file or directory request?

Is it quicker to just send all URI requests to a script and parse it there - or trying to write up all the conditions in an `.htaccess` file? I'm not too familiar with `mod_rewrite`, though.

Comment: mod_rewrite would be the better solution. Try something out and come back with code, there are tons of tutorials online

Comment: Are you sure your directories are named as: `Comics/All%20Star%20Superman` with `%20` used literally.

Comment: No, spaces. I would want spaces translated to/from hyphens in the requesting URL. The directories and files do have spaces in them.

Comment: So your directory is like this: `Comics/All Star Superman` ?

Comment: Yes, true path: `.com/read/Comics/All Star Superman/All Star Superman 01.cbr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this complex handling will be possible in mod_rewrite itself. Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# convert all the hyphens to spaces(%20) recursively
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-(.*)$ /$1\%20$2 [L,NE]

# forward all read/... requests to /index.php
RewriteRule ^(read)/((?:[^/]+/)+?)([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/index.php?dir=$2&file=$3.cbz&page=$4 [L,NE,NC]
```

Comment: As specified in Apache's [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l), if a rewrite rule has the `L` flag, the engine will not process any further rules after this one _if_ it is matched.

Comment: @ChaotiCc: You're actually misinterpreting that sentence. It just means no further rule in the current scope will be executed (i.e. another RewriteRule matching condition). However Apache will **keep executing all of your rules again & again as long as some condition is matching**

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks for pointing that out! Guess I learned something today :-)

Comment: adding in hyphens to a request `read/some/some-test-test/3` results in an error 404. edit: wanted to say that this is working so far, I changed it a bit as such: `#RewriteRule ^((?:[^/]+/)+?)([^/]+)/([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])/?$ /read/test/index.php?dir=$1&file=$2&page=$3 [L,NE,NC]
#RewriteRule ^((?:[^/]+/)+?)([^/]+)/?$ /read/test/index.php?dir=$1&file=$2 [L,NE,NC]` to insure that last is a number then it's a page, if not then it's a file. I reverted back to your provided code though and still getting error 404 with hyphens.

Comment: @Skryn: I thought your URI scheme would be: `read/some/<dir-name>/<file-name>/<page-name?` My answer is based on this scheme, pls let me know if there is another case to handle.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, that's essentially correct. Everything's working except for rewriting hyphens as spaces (%20), but that's easy enough to handle on the script side with a `str_replace()`. Thank you very much. I definitely appreciate this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this on htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^read/index.php?dir=(.+)/(.+)&file=(.+).cbr&page=(\d+)$  read/$1/$2/$3/$4 [NC,L]
```

Comment: `?dir` is not necessarily 2 deep, it can be many sub directories. Also, I want it the other way around, I think... the clean version should be the request, and rewritten to `index.php` with the values.